# Can I send an empty HTTP POST WebRequest object from C# to IIS?

Tags: c#, iis-7, webrequest

Do I need to just slap some random garbage data in a `WebRequest` object to get by the HTTP status code 411 restriction on IIS?

I have an HttpPost action method in an MVC 3 app that consumes a POST request with all the relevant information passed in the querystring (no body needed).

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult SignUp(string email) { ... }
```

It worked great from Visual Studio's built in web host, Cassini. Unfortunately, once the MVC code was live on IIS [7.5 on 2008 R2], the server is pitching back an HTTP error code when I hit it from my outside C# form app.

> The remote server returned an error:
>   (411) Length Required.

Here is the calling code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://somewhere.com/signup/?email=a@b.com");
request.Method = "POST";
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream)) {
    // Do something with responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out you can get this to go through by simply slapping an empty content length on the request before you send it.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://somewhere.com/signup/?email=a@b.com");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = 0;
```

Not sure how explicitly giving an empty length vs. implying one makes a difference, but IIS was happy after I did. There are probably other ways around this, but this seems simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are required to set a Content-Length header anytime you post a request to a web server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.contentlength.aspx

You could try a GET request to test it.